# Fixing a large number of Database Conflict Errors in old Plone 2.5.5

Tags: plone, zope

We have started to get a large number of Database Conflict Errors in an old Plone site (2.5.5 on Zope 2.9.6).  More than 250 in the last 8 hours.  The site is noticeably slower too.

They are occuring even when serving static resources so I don't understand how a write conflict can be happening.  See:

```
2013-08-22T08:46:02 INFO ZPublisher.Conflict ConflictError at /VirtualHostBase/http/www.mysite.com:80/mysite/VirtualHostRoot/portal_javascripts/Plone Default/ploneScripts9172.js: database conflict error (oid 0x0238, class BTrees._OOBTree.OOBTree, serial this txn started with 0x03a0e11203373444 2013-08-22 07:46:00.753666, serial currently committed 0x03a0e11209244055 2013-08-22 07:46:02.142564) (35 conflicts (0 unresolved) since startup at Thu Aug 22 07:39:40 2013)
------
2013-08-22T08:46:22 INFO ZPublisher.Conflict ReadConflictError at /VirtualHostBase/http/www.mysite.com:80/mysite/VirtualHostRoot/favicon.ico: database read conflict error (oid 0x0239, class BTrees._OOBTree.OOBTree) (36 conflicts (0 unresolved) since startup at Thu Aug 22 07:39:40 2013)
------
2013-08-22T08:46:22 INFO ZPublisher.Conflict ConflictError at /VirtualHostBase/http/www.mysite.com:80/mysite/VirtualHostRoot/portal_css/Plone Default/ploneStyles1892.css: database conflict error (oid 0x0239, class BTrees._OOBTree.OOBTree, serial this txn started with 0x03a0e10b728d5655 2013-08-22 07:39:26.848148, serial currently committed 0x03a0e1125f2a1388 2013-08-22 07:46:22.304147) (37 conflicts (0 unresolved) since startup at Thu Aug 22 07:39:40 2013)
```

What can I do to fix or further diagnose this?

Comment: Try to catch in the Z2.log what is the problematic operation. You can read this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope2/+bug/740831. If the problem is long running requests, use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.LongRequestLogger to find the culprit.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion about ConflitError: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/zope/users/209231

Comment: Total shot in the dark: try packing your database. It's a good quick test to see if you've got some kind of extreme data corruption.

Comment: Packed it already.  Packs ok but no improvement in symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

If something is causing writes to your database it will be visible on ZMI *Undo* tab of your site root.

http://developer.plone.org/troubleshooting/transactions.html#how-to-debug-which-object-causes-conflicterrors

If the writes are not visible on *Undo* tab then it is a lower level ZODB problem.

Comment: The undo tab is only showing legitimate edits of the site content.  Now 274 conflicts in the last 9 hours, very worrying.

Comment: How do I proceed addressing a lower level zodb problem?

Comment: What I would do is that I would hack ConflictError code itself to print some debugging log on the production what's going on and which objects clash. Unfortunately this is very advanced stuff, Plone 2.5 is somewhat old already, so finding persons who have necessary skills to debug the issues can be hard.